# Whether to use a definite or indefinite article when we talk about punctuation marks?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Example 1:

> - Option A: **A** question mark is used only at the end of a sentence.
> - Option B: **The** question mark is used only at the end of a sentence.

Example 2:

> - Option A: **A** ? character is used only at the end of a sentence.
> - Option B: **The** ? character is used only at the end of a sentence.

Which sentences are correct, A or B? It seems that in most cases people use the indefinite article in such sentences, but from my point of view "?" exists in a single instance; we just refer to this instance here and there.

Comment: Option **C**: Question **marks are** used only at the end of **sentences**.

Comment: A followed by The is the common thing in English. A dog is a wondrous animal. The dog on my lawn is one. That is the **pattern** for a generalitty followed by a specific instance of the thing.

Comment: @Lambie - Unless the thing is **widely known to be unique**. For example, we say "**The** sun rises in **the** east," not, "**A** sun rises in **an** east."  Which article we use with "question mark" depends on whether we're thinking it of one example of many question marks, or the unique '?' character.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Please don't bother teaching me English. An apple is day is good thing to eat. An apple. The apple on the table is mine. And this is the most usual difficulty for Slavic language speakers. That is the practical thing most of them need to learn. Thank  you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[All three versions occur...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A%20question%20mark%20is%20used%2CThe%20question%20mark%20is%20used%2CQuestion%20marks%20are%20used&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CA%20question%20mark%20is%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThe%20question%20mark%20is%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQuestion%20marks%20are%20used%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...and for the *exact* context as specified<sup>1</sup>, it doesn't really make any difference which you choose. They all mean the same, they're about equally common, and they're all the same "register" (none are particularly more or less "formal / literary / colloquial / whatever" than any others).

---

<sup>1</sup> I can't see it makes any difference whether we're talking about ***question marks, hash characters,*** or ***hyphens*** (or indeed ***any*** punctuation marks) here.

Comment: A followed by The is very common in English. These things don't exist in a vacuum....

Comment: True, but by default NGrams is case-sensitive, so all three search strings represent ***the start of sentences***. And I see no reason to suppose I'd choose the ***a*** version just because I wanted to go on and make some further assertion about ***the*** specific contextually relevant punctuation mark that somehow confirms or refutes my earlier "generic" statement.